# How to create roles in Laravel Passport?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to assign specific role for registered user to distinct access in application. As instance I need roles: admin, operator.

Is it possible to do with Laravel Passport?

Whats difference between grand and role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such thins as roles on passport, you have scopes. As for the grant types they define a flow which your app should follow in order to get valid credentials, i recommend you to read the following article and to look for oauth2 documentation so you get a little more insight on the matter.

https://laravel-news.com/passport-grant-types

@Karim soubai already mention how to achieve roles.